# Why is it possible for me to redeclare a const in go?

Tags: go

For exmaple

```
package main

import "fmt"

const s string = "constant"

func main() {
    const s = 0
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

actually prints

```
0
```

Yet I declared it as "constant" before main.

I thought you were unable to change a constant. If this is not the case, why not use other types?

Answer (score 8):

It's a new constant in the scope of `main`. It doesn't change the one in the outer scope. Look up shadowing.

This program demonstrates it well:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    const a = 0
    fmt.Println(a)
    {
        const a = 1
        fmt.Println(a)
    }
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
0
1
0
```